# Using jQuery pixel detection to change menu layout

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm very new to coding and need some help.

I am trying to get my webpage to detect when a user's pixel size is within 768 and 1200px and I plan to change the way the menu works when someone fits within this parameter.

This an example of my code:

```
if (@media < 768px && @media >1 200px){
    Then
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myMenuButton').menu({
            content: $('#myContent').html(),
            maxHeight: 180,
            positionOpts: { offsetX: 10, offsetY: 20 },
            showSpeed: 300
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this need to change dynamically when the browser changes size too? Also, are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes im using bootstrap, ive already set it so the menu items turn into a toggle box when the screen drops below a certain pixel size but as I have dropdown menus they are over lapping eachother, I want to do something so when the toggle button becomes active that the menu's dropdown to the right instead of going straight down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `$(window).resize()` event. For example, you can do this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //Get the user's width
    if (windowWidth < 1200 && windowWidth > 768){
        //Do code
    }
});
```

Documentation for resize event: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Note that you're better to wrap the above code into document ready
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: ill explain a little more on the situation, im currently using bootstrap with my website and it already changes the menu to a toggle menu when the users pixel size drops below 1200px, but as im using dropdown menu's it becomes very messy as the dropdown menus cover eachother so what im trying to do is change the way the menu's work between these pixel sizes so instead of dropping down, on hover of a menu item it expands to the right.

Comment: Seems to me like a CSS problem... You have to style it properly the way you want using the CSS breakpoint, and then, with the code above, you can control what you want to happens between X and Y window's width

Comment: ok so when it drops below a certain pixel side my css class is called .nav-toggle what would I have to put under that to make on so when you hover over a dropdown menu that is shows to the right of the original menu item rather than dropping down right below the current item?

Comment: It's a little bit hard for me to tell without seeing the design, but I guess if your should position the first element of your menu (li) to 'position relative', and the position the other dropdown using absolute position...

Here's a tutorial for you maybe? Wtihout seeing the layout it's pretty hard to tell what CSS you should write...

are you using jQuery UI also?